# Magento 1.9 Recurring profile error

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to finalize a recurring purchase in magento and I'm getting this error below

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`loja`.`sales_recurring_profile`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_RECURRING_PROFILE_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE), query was: INSERT INTO `sales_recurring_profile` (`state`, `customer_id`, `store_id`, `method_code`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `start_datetime`, `internal_reference_id`, `schedule_description`, `period_unit`, `period_frequency`, `period_max_cycles`, `billing_amount`, `currency_code`, `shipping_amount`, `order_info`, `order_item_info`, `billing_address_info`, `shipping_address_info`, `profile_vendor_info`, `additional_info`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '2020-03-31 14:34:25', '2020-03-31 14:34:25', '2020-03-31 14:34:25', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: It seems no one uses it. :( I'm struggling with the same issue/bug now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Magento have created this foreign key expecting that the customer specified in sales_recurring_profile table exists in customer_entity table.

The problem is that (out of the box) **the client is never created by Magento in orders with recurring items**. Even in the cases that the client has defined a password to create a new account. Magento simply ignore it.

If the customer is new, the `customer_id` property is defined as `true` and later converted to `1`.

## Solution:

Drop this foreign key.

```sql
    alter table sales_recurring_profile
        drop foreign key FK_SALES_RECURRING_PROFILE_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID;
```

### Rolling back

In case you want to rollback the drop, just add it back.

```sql
    alter table sales_recurring_profile
       add constraint FK_SALES_RECURRING_PROFILE_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID
          foreign key (customer_id) references customer_entity (entity_id)
             on update cascade on delete set null;
```

## Conclusion

No one uses or have explored the recurring profile in Magento 1 enough, that's why it's "beta" as you can see in the Sales menu.

Dropping the key is not really recommended because you are changing something inside magento's core. The proper solution would be digging into the checkout proccess, and rewrite the part that makes the mess by creating the customer late in the process.

But, honestly, I'm not going that way, as many other modules could be doing the same and that could cause many conflicts. I still believe this is not a change with big consequences. Time will tell. :)